# What is the difference between starting slapd through service and slapd command?

Tags: redhat, openldap

What is the difference between running slapd using

```
service slapd start
```

OR

```
slapd
```

?

How can I pass options to the `service slapd start` command, like `slapd -h ldap:// -f salpd.conf`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like everything RedHat, `service slapd start` more or less runs `/etc/init.d/slapd start`. So just read the script and figure it out (hint: `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`).

Answer (score 0):

First and most importantly, from the usage standpoint, it provides a standard interface that everybody can approach.  I don't have to worry about what commands `slapd` takes versus `apache`, or `samba`, or any other service.  It also means I can jump between any distributions with a reasonably safe expectation that I can start and stop services in an almost identical way.  By using `/etc/sysconfig` for configuration, it also means that I can edit the way it starts up without having to delve into foreign code, potentially messing something up along the way.

On the technical aspect, not every application provides a nice way to daemonize itself.  Some have no ability to background, others won't orphan a child so that when the shell closes the application closes.  Using it as a service also allows the system to maintain when it runs, including at system startup.  Using the SySV init scripts defined in `/etc/init.d/functions` in RedHat, it also allows it to formalize the interface--that is, check the status, restart, stop, start, etc..